# Como não apresentar no html as chaves de um vetor em aplicação VUE.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estou mexendo em uma aplicação simples com Vue.js, ao marcar alguns checkbox as opções marcadas são apresentadas no Html, até aí funciona normal, só que o problema é que os colchetes do vetor ficam aparecendo tbm. Tem como não apresentá-los.

```js
var app = new Vue({

  el: '#app',
  data: {              
    frames: Array()
  }

})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css"/>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

<label>QUAIS FRAMEWORKS MAIS GOSTA?</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="VUE" v-model="frames">VUE
<input type="checkbox" value="REACT" v-model="frames">REACT
<input type="checkbox" value="ANGULAR" v-model="frames">ANGULAR 

<p> Resposta: {{ frames }} </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas utilize o método [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) para transformar o array em uma string, separando os elementos pela virgula ( ou qualquer outro separador que deseje ).

```
<p> Resposta: {{ frames.join(', ') }} </p>
```

#### Veja funcionando

```js
var app = new Vue({

  el: '#app',
  data: {              
    frames: Array()
  }

})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css"/>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

<label>QUAIS FRAMEWORKS MAIS GOSTA?</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="VUE" v-model="frames">VUE
<input type="checkbox" value="REACT" v-model="frames">REACT
<input type="checkbox" value="ANGULAR" v-model="frames">ANGULAR 

<p> Resposta: {{ frames.length === 0 ? 'Selecione um Framework': frames.join(', ') }} </p>

</div>
```

#### Referência:

- [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Obrigado man, realmente não tinha pensado em utilizar algum método js para tratar o conteúdo do array.